# How to migrate all my Google data to another acount?

Tags: google-account, export

I'm using Gmail, Google Reader, calendar, Picasaweb and other services.

I've decide to change my Google ID. And I am moving Gmail data first (via POP3), but it is a very hard job. I'm afraid to move other services' data. Does Google supports migrating from one account to another?

Comment: this link pretty much matches what you want..http://lifehacker.com/5602545/how-to-migrate-your-entire-google-account-to-a-new-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible to [merge Google accounts](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63304), but it can be done on a [per product basis](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58582). Otherwise, you will need to find workarounds that are not official Google protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe it's currently possible to transfer Picasa-web contents:   your only option would be to use Takeout to download the contents, and then re-upload them.  This would, of course, change the URLs of all your photos.

Comment: Updating this one year later: I believe it is now possible to transfer album ownership.  However I have yet to investigate the impacts of Google's shift toward using Photos+ instead of PWA whenever possible.