# Abandoning immature Gmail address for formal address. How do I minimize the pain of switching within other Google Apps?

Tags: gmail, google, google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate all my Google data to another acount?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23575/how-to-migrate-all-my-google-data-to-another-acount)

I'm leaving for college next year, and I want to leave behind my lame email address.  I created a new address that is just my name.  I know that I can have GMail forward my email from my old address to my new address, but the old address is also associated with:

- My personalized search settings (creepy as it may be, its helpful too)
- Bookmarks
- Youtube
- Google News
- Google Reader
- Google+
- Google Docs
- Google Calendar

not to mention a slew of other sites (stackexchange included).

I've come to terms with having to update my email info on external sites. Is there any way simply make it so that logging in with my new email on these sites gives me access to my old "account" if that makes sense.  In other words, I want to log in with the new email, and still get the same feeds and saved content in Google reader, the same videos and comments on youtube, the same documents on google docs, the same profile information on Google+, etc.

I can't imagine that Google doesn't have a simple way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you keep your old address as your main one, and just use the new one for professional stuff, like to put on your resume?

Comment: Honestly, just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Sigh. Most likely.  A mod can delete/redirect/merge this or whatever then.  Thanks.